# Criar relatorio com listas aninhadas

Tags: ireport, jasper-reports

Gostaria de saber por favor como criar relatório no `Ireport` levando em conta que a figura presente nesse post tem três coleções aninhadas.

Onde uma tabela tem `N` `vigências` e uma `vigência` tem `N` `faixas`.

Gostaria de saber por favor como fazer este tipo de relatório no `Ireport`.

Classe `Persistent` só tem id do tipo `Long`, não vai alterar em nada.

Classe TabelaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo

```
public class TabelaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo extends Persistent {

    private String nome;
    private Boolean desativada;
    private Boolean tabelaNaoPodeSerVinculadaLojas;
    private Boolean tabelaExclusivaParaCPGarantia;
    private Boolean tabelaUtilizadaParaFinanciamentoVeiculos;
    private Short anoFabricacaoVeiculoMin;
    private Short anoFabricacaoVeiculoMax;
    private Float financiamentoPermitidoSobreValorVeiculo;
    private Float endividamentoPermitidoSobreRenda;
    private List<VigenciaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo> vigencias;

    private VigenciaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo vigenciaCorrente;
    private VigenciaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo vigenciaProxima;

    // getters e setters
}
```

Classe VigenciaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo

```
public class VigenciaTaxasComissoesEmprestimo extends Persistent {

        private Date dataInicial;
        private Date dataFinal;
        private List<FaixaTaxaComissaoEmprestimo> faixas;

        // getters e setters
    }
```

Classe FaixaTaxaComissaoEmprestimo

```
public class FaixaTaxaComissaoEmprestimo extends Persistent {

    private Short prazoMinimo;
    private Short prazoMaximo;
    private Float taxaJuros;
    private Float taxaDiferenciadaParaBanco;
    private Float comissao;
    private Float complementoComissao;

    // getters e setters
}
```

Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estou supondo que você já tem os conhecimentos básicos em iReport. Você não colocou seus modelos de objeto, então vou imaginar um conforme sua descrição (na verdade, você deve usar os mesmos objetos do domínio da sua aplicação; algumas pessoas tem uma certa dificuldade para trabalhar deste modo, e muitos vezes fazem um de/para dos dados antes de mandar um objeto Java para o Jasper renderizar). Eu me baseei em JRBeanCollectionDataSource mas é facilmente adaptável para outros tipos de DataSources (XML, Connection, ResultSet ...).

### Resolução do problema

Como você já deve saber, a melhor maneira de "iterar" sobre uma lista, é através de um sub-report. Ainda sem sair deste conceito, para ter um relatório/arquivo de fácil manutenção e que consequentemente suporte evolução, você deve imaginar o seu layout no iReport de maneira modular e que seja coeso com seu modelo de negócio. Observe a imagem descrita por você, começando pelo modelo **Tabela**:

[image: View para classe Tabela.java]

Novamente, sabendo que já é de seu conhecimento que a banda "detail" no ireport irá repetir para cada objeto no [DataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/) (ou cada objeto enviado na lista do JasperReport) eu passo para o sub-report de **Vigencia** as vigencias da **Tabela** atual, layout:

[image: View para classe Vigencia.java]

O mesmo conceito será aplicado aos itens da **Faixa**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A chamada no java, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
    Tabela tabela = new Tabela();

    tabela.setDescricao("Taxa 1%");
    tabela.setStatus("Ativa");

    Vigencia vigencia = new Vigencia();
    vigencia.setDescricao("Vigencia a partir de 31/07/2014");

    tabela.getVigencias().add(vigencia); // forçando repetir
    tabela.getVigencias().add(vigencia);

    Faixa faixa = new Faixa();

    faixa.setPrazo("37");
    faixa.setTaxaDeJuros("1.00%");
    faixa.setTaxaParaBanco("0.50%");
    faixa.setComissao("4.55%");
    faixa.setComplemento("6.00%");

    vigencia.getFaixas().add(faixa); // forçando repetir
    vigencia.getFaixas().add(faixa);
    vigencia.getFaixas().add(faixa);

    List<Tabela> tabelas = Arrays.asList(tabela);

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * isto é como eu resolvo os subreports, mas existem outras maneiras 
     * mais elegantes sem usar FileResolver
     */
    parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER, new FileResolver() {

        public File resolveFile(String fileName) {

            return new File(Main.class.getResource("/jasper/" + fileName).getFile());
        }
    });

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/jasper/tabela.jasper"), parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(tabelas)); 
    ...
```

O que nos gera a saída:

[image: Saida]

E atendendo sua complexidade (o que de fato não é complexo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Fonte dos Arquivos

**tabela.jrxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="tabela" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="borda">
        <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="descricao" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[descricao]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[status]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="vigencias" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[vigencias]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="0" y="0" width="75" height="50"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Tabela]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="75" y="0" width="75" height="50"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Vigência]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="150" y="0" width="405" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Taxa e comissões por prazo]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="150" y="25" width="81" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Prazo (em meses)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="231" y="25" width="81" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Taxa de juros]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="312" y="25" width="81" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Taxa para banco]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="393" y="25" width="81" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Comissão]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="474" y="25" width="81" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Complemento]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="borda" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="75" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{descricao} + "\n" + "(" + $F{status} + ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="75" y="0" width="480" height="25"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{vigencias})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["vigencia.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**vigencia.jrxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="vigencia" pageWidth="480" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="480" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="borda">
        <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="descricao" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[descricao]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="faixas" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[faixas]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement style="borda" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="75" height="25"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{descricao}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="75" y="0" width="405" height="25"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{faixas})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["faixa.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**faixa.jrxml** (81px * 5 = 405px):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="faixa" pageWidth="405" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="405" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="borda">
        <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#666666"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="comissao" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comissao]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="complemento" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[complemento]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="prazo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[prazo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="taxaDeJuros" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[taxaDeJuros]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="taxaParaBanco" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[taxaParaBanco]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="243" y="0" width="81" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{comissao}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="324" y="0" width="81" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{complemento}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="0" y="0" width="81" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{prazo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="81" y="0" width="81" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{taxaDeJuros}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="borda" x="162" y="0" width="81" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{taxaParaBanco}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

### Como é chamado o sub-relatório ?

Na aba "Paleta", selecione o elemento "Subreport", na propriedade "Data Source Expression" coloque:

`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(/*expressao que resultado em uma referencia para java.util.Collection (geralmente um java.util.List) */)`

Em "Subreport Expression", coloque o nome do seu sub-relatório: relatorioABC **.jasper**

### Modelos usados

- Tabela.java

```
public class Tabela implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 203356217547759664L;

    private String descricao;

    private String status;

    private List vigencias;

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List getVigencias() {
        if (vigencias == null) {
            vigencias = new ArrayList();
        }
        return vigencias;
    }

    public void setVigencias(List vigencias) {
        this.vigencias = vigencias;
    }
}
```

- Vigencia.java

```
public class Vigencia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4743305406353605507L;

    private String descricao;

    private List faixas;

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public List getFaixas() {
        if (faixas == null) {
            faixas = new ArrayList();
        }
        return faixas;
    }

    public void setFaixas(List faixas) {
        this.faixas = faixas;
    }
}
```

- Faixa.java

```
public class Faixa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1713006520166696857L;

    private String prazo;

    private String taxaDeJuros;

    private String taxaParaBanco;

    private String comissao;

    private String complemento;

    public String getPrazo() {
        return prazo;
    }

    public void setPrazo(String prazo) {
        this.prazo = prazo;
    }

    public String getTaxaDeJuros() {
        return taxaDeJuros;
    }

    public void setTaxaDeJuros(String taxaDeJuros) {
        this.taxaDeJuros = taxaDeJuros;
    }

    public String getTaxaParaBanco() {
        return taxaParaBanco;
    }

    public void setTaxaParaBanco(String taxaParaBanco) {
        this.taxaParaBanco = taxaParaBanco;
    }

    public String getComissao() {
        return comissao;
    }

    public void setComissao(String comissao) {
        this.comissao = comissao;
    }

    public String getComplemento() {
        return complemento;
    }

    public void setComplemento(String complemento) {
        this.complemento = complemento;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade, vc teria como postar o código fonte por favor?

Comment: Editei e coloquei o fonte dos modelos. Qual seria exatamente sua dificuldade ?

Comment: Cara como você disse, eu dei mole porque deveria ter postado a estrutura de classes mas já foi, estou tendo problemas ao gerar, talvez seja na parte onde se pega o relatório na pasta.

Comment: Você pode usar as que eu anexei, elas seguem 1 Tabela para N Vigencias que tem N Faixas. Mas comente aqui sua estrutura para chegarmos a um concenso :)

Comment: Vou postar lá acima as classes mas não vai mudar muito, mas é o seguinte, eu vi que você colocou isso `/jasper/tabela.jasper`, eu tenho que ter um arquivo deste tipo?

Comment: `/jasper/` é apenas um diretório para meus arquivos jasper, os *.jasper são os compilados (dos *.jrxml) gerados pelo iReport. Se quiser compilar em tempo de execução, você deve fazer algo como: `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(Main.class.getResource("/jasper/tabela.jrxml").getFile());`. Mas eu não recomendo este metodo, afinal, você estaria compilando toda vez que fosse gerar um relatório.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17533/discussion-between-macario1983-and-wryel).