# Problema ao colocar vários dados de uma lista em um relatório

Tags: java, pdf, lista, ireport, relatório

Bom dia galera, essa é uma questão um tanto complicada para se explicar, portando farei o possível para que a pergunta fique bem clara.

Tenho uma lista `<UnimedLote>`. Nessa lista tenho vários dados, dentre esses dados tem alguns que quero listar mais de uma vez, por exemplo. Um Beneficiário pode ter vários procedimentos, então cada vez que eu gerasse o relatório ele listasse os procedimentos dentro desse beneficiário, de tal forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem na Data Realização, Descrição Serviço... Os dados são listados dentro do Beneficiário.

Eu consigo listar todos os dados, porém ele sempre repete o nome do Beneficiário, e não lista os procedimentos dentro dele. Eu consigo isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Reparem que eu consigo listar todos porém separados. Alguém pode me ajudar a descobrir onde tenho que arrumar?
Segue código:

```
for (List<UnimedGuia> lst : listaAuxiliar) {

        System.out.println("Numero do rel: " + nRel);
        System.out.println("Nome do Arquivo: " + nomeArquivo1);

        String nomePrestador = lista1.get(nRel).getNomePrestador();
        String[] as = nomePrestador.split("/");
        nomePrestador = as[0];

        filtro = new HashMap<>();

        filtro.put("Registro ANS", lista1.get(nRel).getRegistroANS());
        filtro.put("Nome da Operadora", lista1.get(nRel).getNomeOperadora());
        filtro.put("CNPJ Operadora", lista1.get(nRel).getCnpjOperadora());
        filtro.put("Nr. Demonstrativo", lista1.get(nRel).getNumeroDemonstrativo());
        filtro.put("Data Emissao Demonstrativo", lista1.get(nRel).getDataEmissaoDemonstrativo());
        filtro.put("Data Competencia", lista1.get(nRel).getDataCompetencia());
        filtro.put("CodPrestador", lista1.get(nRel).getCodigoPrestador());
        filtro.put("NomePrestador", lista1.get(nRel).getNomePrestador());
        filtro.put("CNES", lista1.get(nRel).getCodigoCNES());
        filtro.put("NumLote", lista.get(nRel).getNumeroLote());
        filtro.put("DataEnvioLote", lista.get(nRel).getDataEnvioLote());
        filtro.put("NumProtocolo", lista.get(nRel).getNumeroProtocolo());

        filtro.put("ValorProtocolo", lista1.get(nRel).getValorLiberadoGeral());
        filtro.put("ValorProcessadoGeral", lista1.get(nRel).getValorProcessadoGeral());
        filtro.put("ValorGlosaGeral", lista1.get(nRel).getValorGlosaGeral());
        filtro.put("ValorLiberadoGeral", lista1.get(nRel).getValorLiberadoGeral());

        codArquivoPrestador = lista1.get(nRel).getCodigoPrestador();
        relatorio = gerarRelatorio(lst, nRel, nomePrestador, dataSistema);

}
```

Alguns dados são passados por parâmetros para o relatório, pois são dados que não se repetem, como cabeçalho, nome da empresa, etc.
Método que gera o relatório:

```
public boolean gerarRelatorio(List list, int numeroRelatorio,
            String nomePrestador, String dataSistema) {

        JasperReport report = null;
        InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "/br/com/xml/relatorio/LOGO.png");
        filtro.put("Image", image);

        try {
            InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                    "/br/com/xml/relatorio/Relatorio2.jrxml");
            report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pegar arquivos!",
                    "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        try {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, filtro,
                    new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                    "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/" + nomePrestador
                            + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio
                            + ".pdf");

            /* Variaveis necessarias para salvar o Arquivo */
            caminho1 = "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/";
            ext = ".zip";
            nomeArquivo1 = nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_"
                    + numeroRelatorio;
            caminhoCompleto = caminho1 + nomeArquivo1 + ".pdf";

            codAP = Long.parseLong(codArquivoPrestador);
            // salvarArquivos(caminhoRar, ext, nomeArquivo1, codAP);
            relatoriosGerados = numeroRelatorio + 1;

            return true;

            /* Variaveis necessarias para salvar o Arquivo */
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                    null, ex);
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(
                            null,
                            "Erro ao Gerar relatório, verifique se nenhum arquivo está aberto ou se o nome está correto!\n"
                                    + ex, "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

---

Band Detail - Arquivo Jrxml:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Método que preenche a lista com os dados:

```
public List<Procedimentos> realizaLeituraXML(String arquivoXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        //fazer o parse do arquivo e criar o documento XML
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(arquivoXML);

        Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList tagdadosLote = elem.getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosLote");

        List<Procedimentos> listaLote = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.printf("\n tagdadosLote %s ", tagdadosLote.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < tagdadosLote.getLength(); i++) {
            NumeroLote n = new NumeroLote();
            String lote = "";

            Element elementoLote = (Element) tagdadosLote.item(i);
            lote = pegaTag(elementoLote, "unimed:numeroLote");

            NodeList tagGuia = (NodeList) elementoLote.getElementsByTagName("unimed:guia");
            // Como sabemos pela estrutura que só tem 1 elemento não necessitamos de um for podendo fixar o indice.
            NodeList tagdadosGuia = ((Element) tagGuia.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosGuia");

            for (int y = 0; y < tagdadosGuia.getLength(); y++) {

                Procedimentos contato = new Procedimentos();
                NodeList tagBeneficiario0 = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:beneficiario");
                NodeList tagProcedimentos = ((Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimentos");
                NodeList tagProcedimentos1 = ((Element) tagProcedimentos.item(0)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:dadosProcedimento");

                Element elementoBeneficiarioname = (Element) tagdadosGuia.item(y);
                String nomeBeneficiario = (pegaTag(elementoBeneficiarioname, "unimed:nomeBeneficiario"));
                contato.setNomeBeneficiario(nomeBeneficiario);

                for (int a = 0; a < tagProcedimentos1.getLength(); a++) {
                    NodeList tagProcedimento = ((Element) tagProcedimentos1.item(a)).getElementsByTagName("unimed:procedimento");

                    for (int b = 0; b < tagProcedimento.getLength(); b++) {
                        //Aqui é onde pego os demais dados Do arquivo XML e passo para meu objeto "contato"
                        //Deixei vazio pois é um metodo muito extenso

                        listaLote.add(contato);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        //System.err.println("Lista lote: " + listaLote);
        return listaLote;

    }
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54235/discussion-on-question-by-diegoaugusto-problema-ao-colocar-varios-dados-de-uma-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dando uma olhada mais com calma, identifiquei 3 possíveis entidades: Guia, Beneficiario, Procedimento. Onde **1** guia possui **1** beneficiário e **1** beneficiário pode conter **N** procedimentos.

### Olhando os jrxml de perto ...

Este é um resultado aproximado esperado (você deve ajustar conforme seu gosto depois), vou explicar alguns pontos importantes depois. Esta resposta assume que você já tem os conhecimentos básicos do Jasper Report.

[image: resultado esperado]

**guia.jrxml**

[image: guia]

**beneficiario.jrxml**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**procedimento.jrxml**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Pontos importantes

Os pontos que vou citar aqui não são verdades absolutas, são apena pontos importantes que adquiri com experiência em projetos diferentes:

- Um jrxml por entidade. Facilita manutenção e aqui pode haver reaproveitamento de blocos para mais de um relatório.
- Toda vez que for acessar um objeto/associação e notar que aquilo é um bloco de informação exclusivamente daquele objeto, de preferência para sub-relatório (no seu caso, usei esta abordagem no beneficiario.jrxml).
- Precisa iterar uma lista de objetos que aponta para outra lista de objetos ? Use sub-relatórios.
- Precisa imprimir algo logo após um subrelatório (que geralmente possui tamanho dinâmico) utilizando a mesma banda e os dados estão sendo sobrepostos pelos dados do sub-relatório ? Altere a propriedade "Position Type" para float.

### Como foi feita a chamada do sub-relatório ?

Na aba de propriedades do componente de sub-relatório, existe uma propriedade chamada "Connection Type". Selecione a opção "use a Datasource expression".

[image: connection type]

Em Data Source expression, coloque:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(/* expressão que resulte em um objeto que implemente java.util.Collection */)
```

**Não se esqueça** de apontar também para o .jasper do sub-relatório, alterando a propriedade "Subreport Expression".

---

### Fontes jrxml

**guia.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="guia" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["./"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="codigoGlosa" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[codigoGlosa]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="valorGlosa" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[valorGlosa]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="valorLiberado" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[valorLiberado]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="valorProcessado" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[valorProcessado]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="beneficiario" class="com.stackoverflow.pt.model.Beneficiario">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[beneficiario]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="144" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="30" width="555" height="30"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(($F{beneficiario}.getProcedimentos()))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "procedimento.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="62" width="120" height="26"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Total da Guia:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="37" y="88" width="120" height="26"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor Processado Guia (R$)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="157" y="88" width="120" height="26"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor Liberado Guia (R$)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="277" y="88" width="120" height="26"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor Glosa Guia (R$)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="397" y="88" width="120" height="26"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[CÃ³digo Glosa Guia]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="37" y="114" width="120" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{valorProcessado}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="157" y="114" width="120" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{valorLiberado}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="277" y="114" width="120" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{valorGlosa}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="397" y="114" width="120" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{codigoGlosa}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="60" width="555" height="2"/>
            </line>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="30"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Arrays.asList($F{beneficiario}))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "beneficiario.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**beneficiario.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="beneficiario" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="guia" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[guia]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="identificador" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[identificador]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="nome" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nome]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="procedimentos" class="java.util.List">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[procedimentos]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="senha" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[senha]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="52" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="0" width="189" height="26"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="439" y="0" width="116" height="26"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{identificador}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="24" width="120" height="28"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[NÃºmero da Guia/Senha:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="2"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="24" width="555" height="2"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="120" y="24" width="189" height="28"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{guia} + "/" + $F{senha}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="26"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nome do BeneficiÃ¡rio:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="309" y="0" width="130" height="26"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Identificador BeneficiÃ¡rio:]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**procedimento.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="procedimento" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="4.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="codigoServico" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[codigoServico]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="codigoTabela" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[codigoTabela]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dataRealizacao" class="java.util.Date">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dataRealizacao]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="descricaoServico" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[descricaoServico]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="quantidadeExecutada" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[quantidadeExecutada]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="valorGlosa" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[valorGlosa]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="valorLiberado" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[valorLiberado]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="valorProcessado" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[valorProcessado]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="codigoGlosa" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[codigoGlosa]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="33" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="69" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Data RealizaÃ§Ã£o]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="69" y="0" width="100" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DescriÃ§Ã£o ServiÃ§o]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="169" y="0" width="36" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cod Tab]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="205" y="0" width="50" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cod ServiÃ§o]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="255" y="0" width="60" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Qtde Exec]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="315" y="0" width="60" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor Processado]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="375" y="0" width="60" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor Liberado]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="435" y="0" width="60" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor Glosa]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="495" y="0" width="60" height="32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cod Glosa]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="555" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="1" width="69" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[$F{dataRealizacao}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="69" y="1" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{descricaoServico}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="169" y="1" width="36" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{codigoTabela}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="205" y="1" width="50" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{codigoServico}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="255" y="1" width="60" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{quantidadeExecutada}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="315" y="1" width="60" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{valorProcessado}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="375" y="1" width="60" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{valorLiberado}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="435" y="1" width="60" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.math.BigDecimal"><![CDATA[$F{valorGlosa}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="495" y="1" width="60" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{codigoGlosa}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

### Fontes java

Classe que executa o exemplo

**Main.java**

```
package com.stackoverflow.pt;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

import com.stackoverflow.pt.model.Beneficiario;
import com.stackoverflow.pt.model.Guia;
import com.stackoverflow.pt.model.Procedimento;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {

        List<Guia> guias = Arrays.asList(newGuia(4));

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/guia.jasper"), new HashMap<String, Object>(), new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(guias));

        JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
        jasperViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jasperViewer.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Guia newGuia(int numero) {
        Guia guia = new Guia();
        guia.setBeneficiario(newBeneficiario(numero));
        guia.setCodigoGlosa(numero);
        guia.setValorGlosa(somaValorGlosa(guia.getBeneficiario().getProcedimentos()));
        guia.setValorLiberado(somaValorLiberado(guia.getBeneficiario().getProcedimentos()));
        guia.setValorProcessado(somaValorProcessado(guia.getBeneficiario().getProcedimentos()));
        return guia;
    }

    private static BigDecimal somaValorProcessado(List<Procedimento> procedimentos) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(2);
        for (Procedimento procedimento : procedimentos) {
            bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(procedimento.getValorProcessado());
        }
        return bigDecimal;
    }

    private static BigDecimal somaValorLiberado(List<Procedimento> procedimentos) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(2);
        for (Procedimento procedimento : procedimentos) {
            bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(procedimento.getValorLiberado());
        }
        return bigDecimal;
    }

    private static BigDecimal somaValorGlosa(List<Procedimento> procedimentos) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(0).setScale(2);
        for (Procedimento procedimento : procedimentos) {
            bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(procedimento.getValorGlosa());
        }
        return bigDecimal;
    }

    private static Beneficiario newBeneficiario(int numero) {
        Beneficiario beneficiario = new Beneficiario();
        beneficiario.getProcedimentos().addAll(newProcedimento(numero));
        beneficiario.setGuia(String.valueOf(numero));
        beneficiario.setSenha(String.valueOf(numero) + String.valueOf(numero));
        beneficiario.setNome("Nome " + numero);
        beneficiario.setIdentificador(String.valueOf(numero));
        return beneficiario;
    }

    private static List<Procedimento> newProcedimento(int numero) {
        List<Procedimento> procedimentos = new ArrayList<Procedimento>();
        for (int x = 0; x < numero; x++) {
            Procedimento procedimento = new Procedimento();
            procedimento.setCodigoGlosa(x);
            procedimento.setCodigoServico("Servico " + x);
            procedimento.setCodigoTabela("Tab " + x);
            procedimento.setDataRealizacao(new Date());
            procedimento.setDescricaoServico("Descricao " + x);
            procedimento.setQuantidadeExecutada(x);
            procedimento.setValorGlosa(new BigDecimal(x * 1.50f).setScale(2));
            procedimento.setValorLiberado(new BigDecimal(x * 1.50f).setScale(2));
            procedimento.setValorProcessado(new BigDecimal(x * 1.50f).setScale(2));
            procedimentos.add(procedimento);
        }
        return procedimentos;
    }
}
```

### Classes Modelos

#### Guia.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.pt.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Guia implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1581255960613739095L;

    private Beneficiario beneficiario;

    private BigDecimal valorProcessado;

    private BigDecimal valorLiberado;

    private BigDecimal valorGlosa;

    private Integer codigoGlosa;

    public Beneficiario getBeneficiario() {
        return beneficiario;
    }

    public void setBeneficiario(Beneficiario beneficiario) {
        this.beneficiario = beneficiario;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorProcessado() {
        return valorProcessado;
    }

    public void setValorProcessado(BigDecimal valorProcessado) {
        this.valorProcessado = valorProcessado;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorLiberado() {
        return valorLiberado;
    }

    public void setValorLiberado(BigDecimal valorLiberado) {
        this.valorLiberado = valorLiberado;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorGlosa() {
        return valorGlosa;
    }

    public void setValorGlosa(BigDecimal valorGlosa) {
        this.valorGlosa = valorGlosa;
    }

    public Integer getCodigoGlosa() {
        return codigoGlosa;
    }

    public void setCodigoGlosa(Integer codigoGlosa) {
        this.codigoGlosa = codigoGlosa;
    }
}
```

#### Beneficiario.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.pt.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Beneficiario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1926001805008914921L;

    private String nome;

    private String identificador;

    private String guia;

    private String senha;

    private List<Procedimento> procedimentos;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getIdentificador() {
        return identificador;
    }

    public void setIdentificador(String identificador) {
        this.identificador = identificador;
    }

    public String getGuia() {
        return guia;
    }

    public void setGuia(String guia) {
        this.guia = guia;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public List<Procedimento> getProcedimentos() {
        if (procedimentos == null) {
            procedimentos = new ArrayList<Procedimento>();
        }
        return procedimentos;
    }

    public void setProcedimentos(List<Procedimento> procedimentos) {
        this.procedimentos = procedimentos;
    }
}
```

#### Procedimento.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.pt.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

public class Procedimento implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4956642116624448639L;

    private Date dataRealizacao;

    private String descricaoServico;

    private String codigoTabela;

    private String codigoServico;

    private Integer quantidadeExecutada;

    private BigDecimal valorProcessado;

    private BigDecimal valorLiberado;

    private BigDecimal valorGlosa;

    private Integer codigoGlosa;

    public Date getDataRealizacao() {
        return dataRealizacao;
    }

    public void setDataRealizacao(Date dataRealizacao) {
        this.dataRealizacao = dataRealizacao;
    }

    public String getDescricaoServico() {
        return descricaoServico;
    }

    public void setDescricaoServico(String descricaoServico) {
        this.descricaoServico = descricaoServico;
    }

    public String getCodigoTabela() {
        return codigoTabela;
    }

    public void setCodigoTabela(String codigoTabela) {
        this.codigoTabela = codigoTabela;
    }

    public String getCodigoServico() {
        return codigoServico;
    }

    public void setCodigoServico(String codigoServico) {
        this.codigoServico = codigoServico;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidadeExecutada() {
        return quantidadeExecutada;
    }

    public void setQuantidadeExecutada(Integer quantidadeExecutada) {
        this.quantidadeExecutada = quantidadeExecutada;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorProcessado() {
        return valorProcessado;
    }

    public void setValorProcessado(BigDecimal valorProcessado) {
        this.valorProcessado = valorProcessado;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorLiberado() {
        return valorLiberado;
    }

    public void setValorLiberado(BigDecimal valorLiberado) {
        this.valorLiberado = valorLiberado;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValorGlosa() {
        return valorGlosa;
    }

    public void setValorGlosa(BigDecimal valorGlosa) {
        this.valorGlosa = valorGlosa;
    }

    public Integer getCodigoGlosa() {
        return codigoGlosa;
    }

    public void setCodigoGlosa(Integer codigoGlosa) {
        this.codigoGlosa = codigoGlosa;
    }
}
```

[Você pode aproveitar esta resposta para aprender também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32955/criar-relatorio-com-listas-aninhadas)

Comment: Muito obrigado.