# Passar List para um sub relatório e chama-lo no relatório principal

Tags: java, array, relatório, jasper-reports, lista

Galera tenho um método que gera um relatório pdf em um determinado diretório, agora surgiu a necessidade de usar um sub relatório, porém estou com dificuldade em entender como posso passar uma `List` como data source pra esse `sub relatório` e depois exibi-lo no relatório principal.

Esse é o meu método que gera o relatório principal:

```
public boolean gerarRelatorio(List list, int numeroRelatorio, String nomePrestador, String dataSistema) {
        JasperReport report = null;
        InputStream image = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/LOGO.png");
        filtro.put("Image", image);
        try {

            InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/xml/relatorio/Relatorio3.jrxml");
            report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pegar arquivos!", "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        try {

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, filtro, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                    "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/" + nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio + ".pdf");

            /*Variaveis necessarias para salvar o Arquivo no Banco de dados*/
            caminho1 = "C:/Demonstrativos/" + dataSistema + "/";
            ext = ".zip";
            nomeArquivo1 = nomePrestador + "_" + dataSistema + "_" + numeroRelatorio;
            caminhoCompleto = caminho1 + nomeArquivo1 + ".pdf";

            codAP = Long.parseLong(codArquivoPrestador);
            relatoriosGerados = numeroRelatorio + 1;
            return true;
            /*Variaveis necessarias para salvar o Arquivo  no Banco de dados*/
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPegaXml.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao Gerar relatório, verifique se nenhum arquivo está aberto ou se o nome está correto!\n" + ex, "ERRO!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return false;
        }

    }
```

--
Tentei passar a lista e o caminho por parâmetro da seguinte forma:

```
filtro.put("listaDados", lista);
filtro.put("localizarRel", "src/br/com/xml/relatorio/subRelatorio.jasper");
```

Porém da esse erro:

```
15/05/21 10:36:25 ERROR fill.JRFillSubreport: Fill 1: exception
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : dataRealizacao
```

Esse Bean `dataRealização` faz parte do meu `sub Relatório`, algum sabe aonde posso estar errando?

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A resposta desta pergunta pode ser encontrada nesta pergunta que eu já  respondi a algum tempo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32955/criar-relatorio-com-listas-aninhadas :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia! Você tem que criar um parâmetro do tipo List no seu relatório, 
o mesmo tem que estar com o mesmo nome do parâmetro que você esta mandando em código. Exemplo:

```
filtro.put("listaDados", lista);
```

Crie "listaDados" no seu relatório, ai é só mandar para o sub-relatório assim:

new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaDados); 
no dataset da sua lista, no campo "Use a JRDatasource expression" que você
 deve marcar.
Neste caso posso ver que seu relatório ou sub-relatório não esta encontrando o campo `dataRealizacao`, avalia o objeto da sua lista, tem algo errado nele.
Espero ter ajudado! Abraço!