# IReport - Sub relatório com mesmo datasource do principal

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, relatório

Estou desenvolvendo um `relatório` e o mesmo possui um `subrelatorio` que deve ter o mesmo `DATA SOURCE` do `relatório` principal, para isso o `dataSourceExpression` do `subreport` ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

O problema é que desta maneira o `subreport` nem renderiza mais no `relatório`.

Estou usando o `iReport 6.1.0`

Comment: Creio que você deva estar misturando os conceitos, para não dizer nunca, raramente você deverá passar o dataSource do relatório pai para o relatório filho. O que você está tentando fazer no iReport ? Imprimir uma lista aninhada no seu relatório ?

Comment: Não, o que estou fazendo é segmentar meu relatório, pois ele tem regiões de cabeçalho e rodapé que só devem ser impressos diante de uma condição, então para que eu não precise condicionar todos os campos decidi por coloca-los dentro de um subrelatorio e condicionar o subrelatorio.

Comment: veja se este post te atende: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32955/criar-relatorio-com-listas-aninhadas , se não atender, edite sua pergunta e coloque a estrutura do seu objeto principal do relatorio (isso se você estiver trabalhando com objetos e não xml ou sql). Outro detalhe, os JRDataSource são praticamente um Iterable, onde quem itera ela é o própio jasper. Como você está tentando passar o REPORT_DATA_SOURCE para um relatório filho, ao menos uma vez o método .next() já foi acionado e você não iria conseguir ver o primeiro elemento (isso pelo menos até o jasper 4).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas resolvi de uma maneira que parece mais correta. Ao invéz de usar subreport para isso acabei usando um "frame" para encapsular os campos e coloquei a condição nesse ""frame". Assim não preciso mais dos subreports. Mesmo assim obrigado pelo norte!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme o primeiro comentário do **wryel** eu estava utilizando um conceito errado, fazendo do jeito certo retirei o subreport e em seu lugar para encapsular os campos utilizei o componente "frame", assim não preciso condicionar todos os campos e sim somente o "frame".

Funcionou perfeitamente, além de otimizar o relatório.